# How does EOS.IO avoid high orphan rates with a short block time?

Tags: consensus, network

EOS.IO has a relatively short block interval of 0.5 seconds. On most blockchains with short block intervals, orphan rates are a problem due to propagation latency, and they need special mitigations to reduce this (such as uncle rewards in Ethereum).

How does EOS.IO prevent or mitigate high orphan rates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DPoS there are **turnwise** block creations of every of the (in EOS) 21 block producers. Therefore orphan or stale blocks which are common in PoW chains, do not usually occure. Any misbehaving block producer should theoretically be voted out.

The [white paper](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#consensus-algorithm-bft-dpos) concludes:

> Under normal conditions a DPOS blockchain does not experience any forks because, rather than compete, the block producers cooperate to produce blocks.

Comment: Is there anything special they do to optimise for the (I think groundbreakingly) short block time? Half a second doesn't seem like a lot of time for block propagation.

Comment: Depends on your definition of grounbreakingly... But under normal conditions it is the nature of DPoS, because you dont solve for a specific hash with leading zeros like in bitcoin. However block size and network conditions have to be fitting as well.

Comment: Obviously I get that DPoS eliminates a lot of the uncertainty, since a block can always be produced immediately when a BP sees the previous block, and that existing DPOS chains already get pretty close to this. I was just curious if EOS has invented any new tricks (such as BPs sending blocks directly to the next BP before anyone else, or some other kind of propagation tricks, or maybe some kind of sharding magic, or blind signatures, or filibustering penalties, etc.) to help further.